# NsThread list task

Tags: iphone, objective-c, multithreading, synchronization, nsthread

Hello everyone
I need to accomplish this (iphone/objective-c) :

- I have my thread it has to perform the operations.
- the main thread assigns a new task to my thread (the tasks are always the same).
- each operation has its own id.
- the main thread when assigning a task to my thread, must check whether this operation is an operation that could stop (cancel) that is running on my thread (if new task id = task running id).
- Do you have any suggestions on how I might accomplish this?
- for this work...NSThread or NSOperation?
- I need a shared data structure and synchronized to the operations?
- how can I handle the abort the transaction without having to kill the thread?
  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

[Take a look](http://www.cimgf.com/2008/02/16/cocoa-tutorial-nsoperation-and-nsoperationqueue/) at `NSOperation` and `NSOperationQueue`.